# What is the best way to display a large set of data (PHP)

Tags: php, large-data

I have a function that connect to about a 1000+ databases and get the data back and put it in an array.

however, the data is so large and I want to display the results on the browser each time the loop goes through a connection  instead of waiting for the whole loop to finish.

or if there is a better way of doing so, please share.

```
function Get_data()
{
 // loop base on the number of available databases
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($client_databases); $i++) {

        // Getting connection for each database
        $database = $this->connect_clients_db($client_databases[$i]);

       // return an array of data from the database
        $ClientShema = $this->getSomeData($database);

        // put the data in array
         $schemas[]=$ClientShema;
    }


     return $schemas;


}
```

example of results would be

loop  1 (database_one)
this is a data coming from database one

loop 2 (database_two)
this is a data coming from database two

Comment: You'll also want to ensure your max execution time setting in php.ini will allow the script to not timeout while running through those loops.

Comment: @crush I am not sure about it, but you can't really control the output/stream. Even if you use flush() most times the output is send after script has ended and not when you call flush().

Comment: @djot Not in my experience, unless you are using AJAX. The OP did not make any indication that he was using AJAX. I'm also not sure it wouldn't work in AJAX.

Comment: Updated with a working test script, and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [*turn on output buffering*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and flush the buffer periodically to the browser.

First, you have to send a certain amount of data to the browser:

```
echo str_repeat(" ", 40000);
```

Next, you need to start output buffering:

```
ob_start();
```

Finally, after you've output what you want to send to the browser, you need to flush the output buffer. I found that I had to call the following three functions to get this to work:

```
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
```

So, your code might look like the following:

```
function Get_data()
{
    echo str_repeat(" ", 40000);

    //loop base on the number of available databases
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($client_databases); $i++) {
        //Start buffering output
        ob_start();

        // Getting connection for each database
        $database = $this->connect_clients_db($client_databases[$i]);

        // return an array of data from the database
        $ClientShema = $this->getSomeData($database);

        // put the data in array
        $schemas[]=$ClientShema;

        //Write some output somewhere here.

        //flush the output buffer here.
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }

    return $schemas;
}
```

---

Here is a block of code you can use to test this technique:

```
<?php

echo str_repeat(" ", 40000);

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    ob_start();

    echo "Hello world.<br/>";
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    usleep(500000);
}
```

Comment: thanks, can someone elaborate how will the buffer work in general

Comment: Thank you, the small nice example had helped a lot.